# Does the implementation of strtoul in glibc conflicts with the C11 standard?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, glibc, c11

The follows is the description of function `strtoul` in `stdlib.h` implemented by glibc:

> Function: unsigned long int strtoul (const char *retrict string, char **restrict tailptr, int base)
>   Preliminary: | MT-Safe locale | AS-Safe | AC-Safe | See POSIX Safety Concepts.
>
> The strtoul (“string-to-unsigned-long”) function is like strtol except it converts to an unsigned long int value. The syntax is the same as described above for strtol. The value returned on overflow is ULONG_MAX (see Range of Type).
>
> **If string depicts a negative number, strtoul acts the same as strtol but casts the result to an unsigned integer**. That means for example that strtoul on "-1" returns ULONG_MAX and an input more negative than LONG_MIN returns (ULONG_MAX + 1) / 2.
>
> strtoul sets errno to EINVAL if base is out of range, or ERANGE on overflow.

It means that, for example, `"-2"` will be converted to `ULONG_MAX - 1`. But the C11 standard [7.22.1.4-8] says:

> The strtol, strtoll, strtoul, and strtoull functions return the converted
>   value, if any. If no conversion could be performed, zero is returned. **If the correct value is outside the range of representable values, LONG_MIN, LONG_MAX, LLONG_MIN, LLONG_MAX, ULONG_MAX, or ULLONG_MAX is returned (according to the return type and sign of the value, if any)**, and the value of the macro ERANGE is stored in errno.

So by the standard, for example, `"-2"` shall be converted to `ULONG_MAX`. Is it a conflict?

Comment: Note that glibc follows [posix](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) more so than the C standard. However C11 7.22.1.4.5 seems to deal with the - sign too, though It's quite unclear to me if that negation should take place before the piece from 7.22.1.4-8 that you're quoting takes place.

Comment: @nos, thanks, but as what I reply to chux, even if it takes place after the overflow conversion, there is still a conflict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably another case of `glibc` implementing a feature before standardization occurred.

Yes it conflicts.

However, I consider glibc's result more useful.  If you need perfect compliance, you can wrap the function to perform the conversion.

Comment: Thanks. I agree with you. Do you know where to report this bug?

Comment: @Shenke:  Depends.  If the bug is in the standard, then it is not clear where to report it.  If you think glibc has a bug, then there needs to be some convincing to replace their standard with a new standard.  Change is likely to upset many existing uses.

Comment: There's no conflict in the `-2` example, glibc correctly follows the standard. (The question misinterprets the standard).  Values more negative than `LONG_MIN` would be a different case although before passing judgement it'd be good to test the actual behaviour of the glibc function rather than trusting the documentation posted (which makes little sense)

Answer (score 4):

No conflict.

> If the subject sequence begins with a minus sign, the value resulting from
>   the conversion is negated (in the return type).  C11dr §7.22.1.4 5

`unsigned` negation is well defined.

> A computation involving unsigned operands can never overflow, because a result that cannot be represented by the resulting unsigned integer type is reduced modulo the number that is one greater than the largest value that can be represented by the resulting type. §6.2.5 9

By the standard, "-2" shall be converted to `ULONG_MAX - 2`.

So maybe "Function: unsigned long ... overflow" text conflicts with the C spec in some manner (specifically the "input more negative than `LONG_MIN` returns `(ULONG_MAX + 1) / 2`)", but `strtoul()` functionality is correct.

Comment: Thanks. As @nos says, I don't know whether the negation takes place before or after the overflow conversion I quotes. But even if it takes place after the overflow conversion as what you say, there might be still a conflict on an input more negative than LONG_MIN, for example, - ULONG_MAX (the implementation will return (ULONG_MAX + 1) / 2 while it shall be 1 by the standard).

Comment: @Shenke I just tested on both a 32 and a 64 bit host, it returned 1.

Comment: @nos I am confused. It seems like the real implementation of glibc is not exactly the same as what it documents. Is the document too old? I find it in this website: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_mono/libc.html

Comment: @Shenke  Per the C spec 7.22.1.4-8, gently implies (notice the ordering of function names and range limits) `strtoul()`, uses the range `[0...ULONG_MAX]`, not `[LONG_MIN ...ULONG_MAX]`.  The negation happens after "value resulting from the conversion" per C11dr §7.22.1.4 5.